# Can sqlcmd.exe path be configured?

Tags: c#, sql, sqlcmd

I want to change the location of sqlcmd.exe from its default place to my desired one. Can I place it in my project directory for example?

Comment: I have place sqlcmd.exe in C drive and its not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try move `Resources`(it is in same dir where sqlcmd.exe is) folder and `sqlcmd.exe` together. My guess `sqlcmd.exe` using resources from that folder.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a .bat file which changes working directory to your desired path and then passes received arguments to sqlcmd.exe.

Answer (score 0):

Fraz, I have tested the following, and it works fine:

Remove both **SQLCMD.exe** and **SQLCMD.rll** from their current folders and place them in the directory you'd like to run SQLCMD.exe from. The RLL file is, by default, found in the **Tools\Binn\Resources** folder of the Microsoft SQL Server Program Files folder. These are the only two files that are required for SQLCMD.exe to work, and the RLL file doesn't have to be in a Resources folder in the new location (it can be in the same directory as SQLCMD.exe).

Once you have done the above, you must add the new location to the **Path** Environment Variable in Windows. On Windows 7, you can access the Environment Variables dialog by navigating to **Control Panel\System and Security\System**, clicking on **Advanced system settings**, and pressing **Environment Variables** on the **Advanced** tab of the resulting dialog box. Once in that dialog, look for the **Path** variable, under the **System variables** heading; once you've found that, select it, click **Edit**, and add the new location of SQLCMD.exe to the end of the current value in the **Variable value** box, preceding it with a semicolon.

Please let me know if you would like anything explained further or you have any questions about this answer. I could help you find the Environment Variables dialog on other versions of Windows, if you'd like.